# Regular expression ^.*(?=.*[\W]).*$ excluding underscore

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a regex expression to match atleast one special character, one digit, an uppercase character and a lowercase character

```
^.*(?=.*[\W]).*$
```

But the above expression is excluding _ (underscore). I did a workaround by using

```
^.*(?=.*[\W_]).*$
```

But I'm not sure which all other special characters this regex expression will exclude. Also please let me know why is [\W] excluding underscores?. Any ideas?

I'm using this expression in vb.net

Comment: Since `\w` matches any of `A-Za-z0-9` and `_`, so `\W` (complementary character class) will exclude the above characters. (Assume the regex engine does not have Unicode extension for `\w`).

Comment: `\w` / `\W` behave somewhat differently in different implementations. Could you include the language you are using?

Comment: It dosen't seems to be an issue related to \W vs \w. \w is not even picking up special characters.

Answer (score 2):

[`\w` is letters, digits, and underscores](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).  Thus, nothing else is being excluded.  This may depend on the language/regex flavor, but it's pretty much the standard.

Comment: Letter may contains Unicode characters - if you are using an engine with Unicode extension (not sure about the terminology here) for `\w` (e.g. .NET, Perl)

Comment: It dosen't seems to be an issue related to \W vs \w. \w is not even picking up special characters.